# Evitar la lectura de archivos .py

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

En la empresa estamos desarrollando un proyecto con python usando una raspberry.  El programa ya está hecho y se pretende comercializar el servicio que hace ese código por lo que requerimos que no se pueda leer ni editar el archivo. El mismo se inicia automaticamente mediante un crontab. Mi pregunta es: ¿Se puede hacer un código en python o algún comando en la shell de Linux para evitar que se pueda ver/editar?

Answer (score 1):

Como la tarea la tienes en crontab, supongo que la está ejecutando root, lo normal para que nadie puede modificar ese archivo es que pongas de propietario a root y que solo él tenga permisos sobre el archivo

```
chown root:root tuprograma.py
chmod 700 tuprograma.py
```

De esta manera solo root será el que pueda usar es fichero.

Answer (score 0):

Cambiando los permisos como indica Sergio bastaría si no se tiene acceso físico a la RPi (sería suficiente con leer la tarjeta de memoria desde otro equipo con acceso root para poder acceder a tu código).

Necesitarás ofuscar el código para que nadie pueda leerlo/editarlo.

Desafortunadamente, Python no es el lenguaje ideal para ofuscar el código, ya que su filosofía es que todo sea un código open source.

Podrías probar a precompilar todo el código en bytecode, borrar los .py y distribuir los .pyc. Para precompilar el código, puedes usar:

```
python -m compileall .
```

Aún así, no sería complicado decompilar el código, pero es una barrera más.

Una solución más efectiva puede ser utilizar Cython para convertir el código Python a C y luego compilarlo con gcc, y así crear librerías dinámicas que se pueden usar como módulos importables. Échale un ojo a su [documentación](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html).

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a tu cuestión depende de varios factores:

- ¿Tienes acceso a la máquina donde se ejecutará el software, y tu cliente en cambio no tiene permisos de root? En ese caso puede ser suficiente quitar los permisos de lectura del archivo a todos los usuarios salvo al que ejecutará el script (típicamente root), que es lo que te han propuesto en otras respuestas.
- ¿Tienes que proporcionar el programa al cliente y él lo instalará? En ese caso no puedes evitar que lo lea, pero hay varios mecanismos que detallaré luego para que lo que lea no tenga sentido para él.
- ¿Qué nivel de conocimientos tiene tu cliente? Si su nivel es muy básico, la solución puede ser tan simple como suministrarle un `.pyc` o `.pyo` en lugar de un `.py`. Estos son versiones "compiladas" en el que las líneas de código fuente han sido convertidas a bytecodes. Si intentas abrir ese archivo con un editor no verás el fuente, sino un caos de símbolos (entre los cuales podrás leer ocasionalmente las cadenas que use tu programa). No obstante existen herramientas para obtener código fuente de nuevo desde el `.pyc`. No obtendrá tu código original (los comentarios no aparecen, algunos nombres estarán cambiados), pero en general lo que se obtiene es bastante legible.
- ¿Es legal tu cliente? En ese caso la solución más simple (y la que realmente se usa en el mundo del Open Source) es no preocuparse de que pueda leer el fuente, sino incluir con el programa una licencia que establezca claramente qué puede hacer con él. Si en la licencia le prohibes modificarlo o copiarlo, o usarlo para otros fines, el cliente debería cumplir los términos de la licencia (lo contrario sería delito).

Si no te fias de que el cliente sea legal y quieres en lo posible evitar que acceda al fuente, puedes intentar alguna de las siguientes soluciones:

- Ofuscar el código. Es decir, renombrar las funciones, las variables, etc. de modo que sus nombres carezcan de sentido. Aunque puede seguir leyendo el código, se hará muy difícil entender qué hace, y por tanto que pueda copiarlo y usarlo en otro proyecto. La herramienta [pyminifier](https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/) puede hacer esto. Al final, una vez pasado por esta herramienta, tu programa puede quedar con un aspecto como este:

  ```py
  import zlib, base64

  exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJx1kcFOwzAMhu95ClMO66apu0/KAQEbE5eJC+IUpa27haVJ5Ljb+vakLYJx4JAoiT/7/+3c3626SKvSuBW6M4Sej96Jq9y1wRM/E3kSexnIOBZObrSNKI7Sl59YsWDq1wLMiEKNrenoYCqB1woDwzXF9nn2rskZd1jDh+9mhOD8DVvAQ8WdtrZfwg74aNwp7ZpnMXHUaltk878ybR/ZNKbSjP8JPWk6wdn72ntodQ8lQucIrdGlxaHgq3QgKqtjhCY/zlN6jQ0oZZxhpfKItlkuNB3icrE4XYbDwEBICRP6NjG1rri3YyzK356CtsGwZuNd/o0kYitvrBd18qgmj3kcwoTckYPtJPAyCVzSKPCMNErs85+rMINdp1tUSspMqVYbp1Q2DWKTJpcGURRDr9DIJs8wJFlKq+qzZRaQ4lAnVRuJgjFynj36Ol7SX/iQXr8ANfezCw==')))
  ```

  Ten claro no obstante que si se lo propone y tiene la habilidad técnica necesaria, puede obtener si no tu código original, sí algo lo bastante parecido como para que pueda serle útil.
- Utilizar criptografía para codificar el ejecutable. El problema de la criptografía es que para poder ejecutarlo hay que desencriptarlo de nuevo, por lo que la clave de desencriptado tiene que formar parte de alguna forma del "ejecutable".

  La herramienta [pyconcrete](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyconcrete/0.11.3) propone una solución ingeniosa. Tú le das una clave (o permites que genere una aleatoriamente), y él crea una versión cifrada de tu código, más un ejecutable específico para poder ejecutar esa versión cifrada. Al cliente le proporcionas ambos. La clave de descifrado está oculta en el ejecutable con técnicas avanzadas. Pero como en el caso anterior, un *hacker* que se lo proponga podrá dar con ella, como ha quedado demostrado en incontables ocasiones con todos los métodos DRM que se han ido inventando.

En última instancia, la forma más segura es el forzarlo "por ley", mediante la licencia ya que si bien no evitarás que si el cliente se lo propone pueda acceder al fuente, al menos podrás tomar acciones legales contra él si lo hace. Puedes combinar entre sí todos los mecanismos anteriores, incluyendo el legal :-)